# How to show entire page in a Pop up(Jquery)

Tags: jquery

I want to show whole page in a pop up of size 300*300.Is it possible?
If yes then how can i do this.please revert back with your valuable answer.
Thanks!!!

Comment: DO YOU MEAN by also change proportions of elements ?

Comment: Use jQuery UI/Modal Dialog. Not a comprehensive comment, but it wasn't that comprehensive a question ;)

Comment: Did you mean new window using window.open ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the jquery 'fancybox' plugin.
With fancybox you can open an entire page in a popup and also specify the size if necessary.

some sample code for your specific case:

*html part : (button with link to page you want to open in popup):*

```
<a class="extLink" href="http://www.openedInIframe.com">This goes to iframe</a>
```

*javascript part : (bind fancybox to button, this is where the magin happens)*

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
         $(".extLink").fancybox({  
              'width' : '300',  
              'height' : 300',  
              'autoScale' : false,  
              'type' : 'iframe'  
          });   
    });
```

for more info on how to implement fancybox in your pages : http://fancybox.net

Answer (score 0):

Popup.js from [**Yen Design**](http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/) works for me. Can customise to your needs and is very small!

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZW4U/19/)